# Solving symbolically system of equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to solve below system of equation in Matlab symbolicaly ? For example, a and b aren't defined below :

x1 - (5-a)x2  = 2
2x1 + 5x2  = b
x1+x2+x3=0

does Matlab (without advenced libraries) can be use to solve this system ? I know that Mathematica offers that possibility, but I'm asked to do this in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!

http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

It doesn't look as cool as Mathematica, but it works.